# Find Sin(i) with SageMath

Tags: math, sage

**How can you find the `sin(i)` with Sage?**

I am trying to do some complex analysis with Sage.

The following commands are not working

```
sin(i)
sinh(i)
```

Comment: It might help to have more context.  Could you post your code and the error messages that tell you it's "not working"?

Comment: sage related questions are asked best in the support forum http://groups.google.com/group/sage-support

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
CDF(0,1).sin()  # or ComplexDoubleField(0,1)   CDF is just a shorthand
```

or

```
sin(CDF(0,1))
```

or

```
sin(1.0*I) # note the .0 to make it a float
```

Essentially CDF() creates a double-based complex number; the first argument is the complex part the second the imaginary part.
ComplexDoubleElement() does the same (I think less tolerant of "odd" types).
I'm not sure of the relation of these with  ComplexNumber().  (maybe the latter is just simple precision ?)

All expressions above return *approximately* (rounding w/ float arithmetic?)

```
1.17520119364*I
```

Answer (score 5):

You just need to use a cap I, so in sage

```
I*I = -1
```

And

```
N(sin(I)) = 1.17520119364380*I
```

At least this works for the online notebook.

Answer (score 3):

These two chapters will provide some good background:

- [Field of Arbitrary Precision Complex Numbers](http://www.sagemath.org/doc/reference/sage/rings/complex_field.html)
- [Arbitrary Precision Complex Numbers](http://www.sagemath.org/doc/reference/sage/rings/complex_number.html)

From that, you can get your answer:

```
ComplexNumber(0,1).sin()
```